# ¿como obtener los campos de todas las filas de una consulta SQL en Java?

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Buenas tardes alguien podria ayudarme con lo siguiente porfavor...
Quiero obtener el ID de las Filas obtenidas por la consulta SQL siguiente y guardarlas en una variable pero no se como hacerlo.

```
SELECT * FROM productos;
```

Pero si se como obtener las columnas de una fila en especifico y guardarlas en una variable,  el codigo que utilizo para obtener las columnas es el siguiente:

```
Connection con;
    //Obtenemos datos de tabla producto
    try {
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/susyken", "root", "");
    String sentencia = "SELECT * FROM producto WHERE Id_Producto="+codigo+";";
    Statement stmt = null; //Esto sustituirá a ps
    stmt = con.createStatement(); //Usamos create... no prepare...
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sentencia);
    while (rs.next()) {
        idProducto = rs.getString(1); //Si codigo es del tipo numérico en la BD debes usar getInt
        nombreProducto = rs.getString(2);
        existencia = rs.getString(3);
        precio = rs.getString(4);
    }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");
    }
```

¿Alguien podria ayudarme a saber como hacerlo?

Comment: Hola Javier, tu código te muestra algún error? de ser así podrías compartirlo.

Comment: ¡Hola Ricardo! Realmente no tengo codigo de eso, el codigo que puse de ejemplo es un codigo el cual si funciona y guarda las columnas de la fila en variables exitosamente pero solo de una fila la cual se obtiene con la consulta, yo lo que necesito es guardar en variables las columnas de todas las filas que se otienen con la consulta SQL no solo una como es el caso de mi ejemplo...

Comment: Veo esta línea `idProducto = rs.getString(1); //Si codigo es del tipo numérico en la BD debes usar getInt`, y solo decir que esto no es del todo cierto. También podrías recuperar el valor mediante un String si no vas a realizar ninguna operación con el y solo mostrar datos por ejemplo. Lo digo por lo que dice el comentario, te funciona igual con `getInt()` o con `getString()`